# Thin line when hovering increment button of JavaFX ScrollBar

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to get rid of a thin line around the increment and decrement buttons of a ScrollBar that only shows when I hover over them.

[image: This is how it looks when I hover over one of the buttons]

This is my CSS:

```
.scroll-pane .scroll-bar > .increment-button > .increment-arrow,
.scroll-pane .scroll-bar > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: #A39A99;
}
.scroll-pane .scroll-bar > .increment-button > .increment-arrow:hover,
.scroll-pane .scroll-bar > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #A39A99;
}
.scroll-bar > .increment-button:hover,
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button:hover {
    -fx-color: #666362;
}
```

I really hope, someone knows what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `#A39A99` color to anything you want,

```
.scroll-bar > .increment-button:hover,
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button:hover
 {
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0;
    -fx-background-color: #A39A99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this:

```
.scroll-bar:hover {
    background-image: url('picture.png');
}
```